# SQL: Help with a nested queries

Tags: sql, mysql, declarative, subquery

Here is my schema:

Suppliers(**sid: integer**, sname: string, address string)

Parts(**pid: integer,** pname: string, color: string)

Catalog(**sid: integer, pid: integer,** cost: real)

**bold** indicates primary key.

I want to write a query to find all suppliers who supply every part. Here are two queries I have already:

```
-- get all parts for a given supplier
SELECT Parts.pid
FROM Suppliers
JOIN Catalog ON Catalog.sid = Suppliers.sid
JOIN Parts ON Parts.pid = Catalog.pid
WHERE Suppliers.sid = 4;

-- gets all parts that exist
SELECT Parts.pid
FROM Parts
```

What I want to do, in imperative terms, is something like this:

```
Define result set
Foreach Supplier:
    If the list of parts produced by a supplier 
    is equal to the total list of parts, add this supplier to the result set
Return result set
```

How can I translate this into MySQL?

Comment: I was going to suggest looking into UNION and MINUS... then I remembered that MySQL does not support MINUS so you'll have to find a way to fake it (and there *are* ways). But generally, I would say that if you subtract a supplier's list of parts from the `ALL PARTS` list, and you have something left over, then that supplier does not supply all parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM SUPPLIER s
  JOIN (SELECT c.sid,
               COUNT(c.pid) AS num_parts
          FROM CATALOG c
      GROUP BY c.sid) x ON x.sid = s.sid
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_parts
          FROM PARTS) y ON y.total_parts = x.num_parts
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it translates to MySQL, but something along these lines:

```
select s.sname, PartCount from (
 select s.SID, s.sname, PartCount = sum(p.PID)
 inner join Catalog c on c.SID = s.SID
 inner join Parts p on p.PID = c.PID
 where s.SID = 4
 group by s.SID
) a
where PartCount = MAX(PartCount)
```

Note labeling the subquery 'a' is an arbitrary name as MSSQL requires names on its subqueries for some reason. Dunno how it works in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (
  SELECT sid, count(pid) as c
  FROM Catalog
  GROUP BY sid) q1
JOIN Suppliers s ON s.sid = q1.sid
WHERE q1.c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Suppliers.sid
FROM Suppliers
INNER JOIN
(SELECT sid, COUNT(pid) as num
    FROM Catalog
    GROUP BY sid)as t1
ON Suppliers.sid = t1.sid
WHERE t1.num = 
    (SELECT COUNT(pid) FROM Parts)
```